# How do I select tail with nulls in sqlite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, null, sequence, gaps-and-islands

I have a sqlite3 DB, where each row has auto-incremented `id` and some value that can be `NULL`. I need to **delete the tail with nulls** (ideally preserving the oldest null record from this segment).
For example, here, I would like to delete rows with **id = 12..16** (or ideally 13..16).

Any idea how can this be done in sqlite?

```
CREATE TABLE tail (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, val TEXT);
INSERT INTO "tail" VALUES(1,'5');
INSERT INTO "tail" VALUES(2,'7');
INSERT INTO "tail" VALUES(3,'100');
INSERT INTO "tail" VALUES(4,'150');
INSERT INTO "tail" VALUES(5,NULL);
INSERT INTO "tail" VALUES(6,NULL);
INSERT INTO "tail" VALUES(7,'120');
INSERT INTO "tail" VALUES(8,'150');
INSERT INTO "tail" VALUES(9,'152');
INSERT INTO "tail" VALUES(10,NULL);
INSERT INTO "tail" VALUES(11,'152');
INSERT INTO "tail" VALUES(12,NULL);
INSERT INTO "tail" VALUES(13,NULL);
INSERT INTO "tail" VALUES(14,NULL);
INSERT INTO "tail" VALUES(15,NULL);
INSERT INTO "tail" VALUES(16,NULL);
```

I can do it easily in two steps, something like:

```
to_delete = []
for row in query("SELECT * FROM tail ORDER BY -id"):
    if row.id IS NOT NONE:
        break
    to_delete.add(row.id)
# optionally: to_delete.remove_last()
query("DELETE FROM tail WHERE id IN (?)", to_delete)
```

But this is not in transaction, and I have a feeling that there is some neat trick that can be used to accomplish this in single sqlite statement.

Comment: Why not just `delete from tail where val is null`? Not super familiar with sqlite so can't help with the syntax there.

Comment: @JacobH I need all val=NULL except those in the tail for some other calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
delete from tail
    where id > (select max(t2.id) from tail t2 where t2.val is not null) and
          val is null and
          id <> (select max(t3.id) from tail t3 where t3.val is null);
```

Comment: It works, thanks Gordon. BTW, isn't `val is null and' redundant or I missed something?

Comment: @MichałŠrajer . . . Yes.  Under the circumstances, it is redundant.